# The inbox and achievement notifications show up incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

In the top bar, it said that I have 1 unread inbox message and earned 7 reputation points:

[image]

But when I clicked on both buttons, I neither had an unread inbox message nor earned reputation. My last inbox message is according to my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5378624/donald-duck?tab=inbox) 16 hours ago, which is before the last time I checked my inbox. Also, the reputation on the three sites where I have an account is exactly the same as the reputation I had last time I looked before these notifications showed up.

This is the second time today this happens with the exact same numbers (1 unread inbox message and +7 reputation). Why does this show up if I don't have any unread inbox messages and haven't earned any reputation?

Comment: Did you come back to your computer after some time away or was this on a fresh page refresh?

Comment: @Catija I opened a new tab and clicked on Stack Exchange in the favorite bar. I didn't have any Stack Exchange page opened before that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nick already tweeted about this when a person complained that he got notification and rep highlight of already seen ones. https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/901151925361627140

> We had a redis server die hard, outdated cache restored temporarily :(

[image]

So the outdated cache restoration may have caused this problem.